# architecture of gui app with several indepedent windows and sqlite backend

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

Let's assume that I have such a simple database scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cap TEXT NOT NULL);
```

I want to show at least three independent GUI windows.
One window (`window A`) with list of items,
if I choose one item it should be possible to open `window B`,
that allow delete or update item. Also it should be possible
to open  `window B` to create new item. 
Ordinary task for many applications I suppose.
But I want to make `window B` to be not modal dialog,
plus allow to create several `window B` type dialogs.

How should I make coherent content of these windows?

For example if I create:

```
struct Record {
  int64_t id;
  std::string text;
};
```

and `class Db` that encapsulate simple `update`, `select`, `insert` and `delete` `SQL` statements it would be not enough.

Because of for example I can open `window B` with last item in `tbl`, maximum value of `key` column, that open again it in other `window B`,
and delete it, after that create new item, and this item will get that same `key` value as deleted one. So I have two `window B` with the same `key`, but different `cap`.

Should I create in `Db` class cache with `std::shared_ptr<Record>`?
And add possibility to subscribe on `std::shared_ptr<Record>` changes?

Or may be there is other standard way to handle situation like this?

Comment: Your parent window needs to know when a commit happens on the child windows.  Perhaps fire an event so that the parent window knows to update it's view?  I don't know what UI framework you are using, so I can't answer more than that.  Even if you use a `std::shared_ptr` you still need to redraw the UI.  Unless your UI has 2-way data binding with your record, you can have all the data in sync but the UI out of sync.

Comment: Design your GUI from the user's point of view. How can your user effectively do what she needs to do in your application? Where does the user need to be supported to prevent making mistakes? Only when you have a good grasp of the functional requirements can you *start* to think about how to design your code. Otherwise, you are almost guaranteed to end up with a mess.

Comment: Which GUI framework do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Your window (or your app) shouldn't be assigning keys - the DB does that. Thus, if you want to create a new record, you just need to ask the user for input on what the `cap` will be. Then `insert` that into the DB as a new record, it returns the new `key` and you update the `Record` object behind the window (or create a new one entirely). This means that, in your scenario, after you delete the last item in `tbl` and create a new one, it will have a different key than the item you just deleted.

You can certainly listen for changes to the `Record`, and update the UI in some fashion (new data available, record no longer exists, etc).

Comment: You missed that I have several independent windows. I have valid map object in memory <-> row in table only in one of them. In other windows I can possibly have wrong info after object was deleted in other window.